# bootstrap fluid-grid layout and container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Bootstrap 3 grid layout:

Question 1: Is it good practice to wrap my entire site with the .container-fluid class and then use rows where needed?

Question 2: when I create a column with something in it (i.e. a rectangle box), is it appropriate to move the rectangle box with positioning(relative, margin, padding)?

Any other helpful tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. No.  Use column offsets.  ex: col-2-lg-offset col-8-lg col-2-lg-offset to center a column.

Answer (score 0):

Container-fluid is width: 100% and padding 15px from left and right. This is called full width layout.
While container is max-width eg. Max-width: 1024px; margin: auto from left and right. 
For move a floating column it's better to use col-offest eg. Col-2-md-offset